# Persistent miss on cylinder #2

Tags: dodge, misfire, grand-caravan

Dodge 2004 Grand Caravan 3.8 motor. Changed plugs, wires, coil pack. #2 cylinder not getting spark. Where should I look next?

Comment: Was #2 Cylinder getting spark before you changed plugs wires coil pack? Can you offer any more information about your situation?